# How to get a day of month from "what I know"?

Tags: php, date

Need some logic here:

Need to get day of month date("d")

What I know:

```
$year = 2013;
$month = 10;
$week_nr_of_month = 3; // from 1 to 6 weeks in month
$day_of_week = 0; // Sunday date("w")
```

Thanks for logic

Result must be: 13 October

Comment: Just calculate a day of month (1 to 31) , using that variables.

Comment: You should try it yourself and afterwards you can come up with some code for us to help you out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fun to figure out.

```
<?php

$year = 2013;
$month = 10;
$week_nr_of_month = 3; // from 1 to 6 weeks in month
$day_of_week = 0; // Sunday date("w")

$start = new DateTime();
$start->setDate($year, $month, '1');
$end = clone $start;
$end->modify('last day of this month');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $date) {
    if ($date->format('w') == $day_of_week) {
        $wom = week_of_month($date->format('Y-m-d'));
        if ($week_nr_of_month == $wom) {
            echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
        }
    }
}

function week_of_month($date) {
    $dt = new DateTime($date);
    $bg = clone $dt;
    $bg->modify('first day of this month');
    $day_of_first = $bg->format('N');
    $day_of_month = $dt->format('j');
    return floor(($day_of_first + $day_of_month - 1) / 7) + 1;
}
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/3XMejT)

Used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10943258/250259) for inspiration to get the week number for the date.

Comment: I'm off by a week so far. Gotta find a better way to narrow down the actual week.

Comment: yeah, result must be 13 october

Comment: no, not working correct for other dates.. for example: Year 2014, month: 1, week nr of month: 3, day of week = 0, showing: 2014-01-12 , must be 2014-01-09

Comment: 2014-01-12 is the correct response. You can verify it by looking at a calendar.

Comment: wow sorry you right. i just sleepy and didnt sow that now is first feb.

Comment: No problem. That was an interesting challenge.

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime` may be of help. Can't test right now, but...

```
$ordinal = array("first","second","third","fourth","fifth");
$weekdays = array("monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday","saturday","sunday");
$timestamp = strtotime($year."-".$month." ".$ordinal[$week_nr_of_month]." ".$weekdays[$day_of_week]);
```

Comment: almost but no.. it's shows 28 October, but need 13 October

Comment: Hmm... try moving "sunday" to the front of the array, and subtract one from the week number...